# User database program

Tags: database

The association that I am part of needs a program for their members who need help with their housing applications.

They need a small program with embedded database like SQLite  (no client-server, no concurrent access).

Only one table, with various fields for each user (name, telephone, address, etc), and a Windows program for introducing new users, searching for the users, and displaying user data.

Also the program must assign and create a folder for each client, where various scans of the person's documentation will be stored. The name of the folder should contain the name of the person and an unique ID

The program must feature a button for opening the folder with the person's file.

Also the program has to provide an interface for adding new fields to the database (to the table in fact), without losing data.

I know I can create such a program myself, but I prefer a program that is already made, with updates and bug fixes if possible.

Is there a generic name for this kind of program? It should be either for Windows, or a web app – preferably free (while paid/commercial programs would be considered, too, as long as they are not too expensive).

Comment: My first thought is [FileMaker](http://www.filemaker.com/products/filemaker-pro/), but I do not know about your open-a-folder feature.

Comment: I would be happy to design and support a program like that. If they're looking me@evancarroll.com. My suggestion if they want a web app would be google contacts.